# ORA 00936 Missing Expression sql statement

Tags: oracle, powerquery

I am trying to get a response from a Oracle client and getting a ORA 00936 Missing Expression Error.

This is the sql I am trying to send:

```
SELECT "Q_FISCAL_DTE",
    "Q_BL_ORG_ID",
    "Q_BP_ID",
    "Q_TPTY_ID",
    "Q_CP_CASH_SUMM_ID",
    "Q_PAYOR_CDE",
    "Q_MKT_SEG_CDE",
    "Q_BU_ID",
FROM "SYSADM"."PS_Q_CP_CASH_SUMM"
WHERE "Q_BU_ID" NOT IN (‘IP’,’ES’,’SJ’,’PR’) 
AND "Q_FISCAL_DTE" > ‘6/1/2021’;
```

Comment: At the very end, you are comparing a column that presumably stores dates (in `date` data type) to a string. That may result in all sorts of errors. Wrap your string ('6/1/2021') within `to_date` with the proper format model: `... > to_date('6/1/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy')`

Comment: Also (just spotted it) the error is caused by the comma after the last column in `SELECT`, right before the `FROM` keyword. Remove that comma - Oracle expects additional column names after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite the query following these advices

- Don't use double quotes unless the metadata ( tables, columns ) is stored in lowercase. Oracle always stored all metadata in uppercase.
- I believe you have a copy & paste error, because the quotation `’` should be `'`
- Last comma is wrong, thus the error you are getting as Oracle is waiting for an additional field.

So, it should be

```
SELECT Q_FISCAL_DTE,
    Q_BL_ORG_ID,
    Q_BP_ID,
    Q_TPTY_ID,
    Q_CP_CASH_SUMM_ID,
    Q_PAYOR_CDE,
    Q_MKT_SEG_CDE,
    Q_BU_ID
FROM SYSADM.PS_Q_CP_CASH_SUMM
WHERE Q_BU_ID NOT IN ('IP','ES','SJ','PR') 
AND Q_FISCAL_DTE > '6/1/2021';
```

However, if `Q_FISCAL_DTE` is a date, then

```
SELECT Q_FISCAL_DTE,
    Q_BL_ORG_ID,
    Q_BP_ID,
    Q_TPTY_ID,
    Q_CP_CASH_SUMM_ID,
    Q_PAYOR_CDE,
    Q_MKT_SEG_CDE,
    Q_BU_ID
FROM SYSADM.PS_Q_CP_CASH_SUMM
WHERE Q_BU_ID NOT IN ('IP','ES','SJ','PR') 
AND Q_FISCAL_DTE >  to_date('6/1/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') ;
```

On the other hand, if the date `6/1/2021` represents day/month/year , then apply the other mask

```
SQL> select to_date('6/1/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') from dual ;

TO_DATE('
---------
06-JAN-21
```

Comment: theres a spurious comma following  Q_BU_ID   last expression in SELECT list.  right on with the part about if Q_FISCAL_DTE is  DATE datatype, and we want to do a comparison, then best practice is to compare to another DATE datatype, and using the Oracle TO_DATE function to convert a string literal to DATE is the way to go.

Comment: @spencer7593, thanks for the tip, copy paste issue. I was trying to cover options because the poster has not confirmed that the field is really a `date` field. I found many times people using `varchar2` or `number` for date fields, that is why I was putting the options depending on the case

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma after last column in SELECT and change quotas ‘ to '.